# Как изменить свойства файла

Tags: php, файлы, metadata

У файла в Windows есть во вкладке подробно набор свойств, я хотел бы при загрузке человеком файла установщика программы на сайте, дописывать в эти свойства, свойства связанные с конкретным посетителем сайта. Например, если он авторизован на сайте, то его имя на сайте.

Сайт соответственно на хостинге с Linux, а свойства будут считываться установщиком msi(кстати это тоже вопрос, возможно ли будет их считать, предполагаю что да) и они видны в Windows. Зависит ли так же наличие этих свойств от операционной системы?

Comment: Какие именно свойства? Скрытый/Архивный или Автор/Компания/Версия

Comment: Второе @Walfter